# Updating Span based on Radio Button Choice

Tags: jquery

I made this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6tZmc/1/

Basically, I would like to update an empty span based on radio button choice. Here is the code:

**html**

```
<div>
<p>Your chose: <span id="animal"></span></p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Pick an Animal:</h2>
<input type="radio" name="pets" value="cat" />Cats<br />
<input type="radio" name="pets" value="dog" />Dogs
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
function petChoice(){
    var chosenPet = $('input[name="pets"]:checked').val();
    if(chosenPet = 'cat'){
        $("span#animal").text();
        $("span#animal").text("Cats");
    }else if (chosenPet = 'dog'){
        $("span#animal").text();
        $("span#animal").text("Dogs");
    }else{
        $("span#animal").text();
    }
}
$("input[name='pets']").click(function(){
    petChoice();
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your if statement you are trying to assign `cats` and `dogs` to `chosenPet` when in fact, you'd like to test equality. Change `=` to `==`

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to wrap you function so that it is executed after the `document` is ready.

Also you can shorten your function by just setting the text to the value of the radio button that was clicked. In jQuery events, `this` refers to the element that triggered the event.

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name='pets']").click(function () {
        $("#animal").text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6tZmc/2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
function petChoice(){
    var chosenPet = $('input[name="pets"]:checked').val();
    if(chosenPet == 'cat'){
        $("span#animal").html("Cats");
    }else if (chosenPet == 'dog'){
        $("span#animal").html("Dogs");
    }else{
        $("span#animal").empty();
    }
}
$("input[name='pets']").click(function(){
    petChoice();
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6tZmc/4/